# PHP for loop order

Tags: php, arrays

I want to ask pretty simple question (for most of you) but I can't find the solution right now.

We have `$names = array('Alex','James','Jack');`

I want to use for loop to echo this:

```
1. Alex
2. James
3. Jack
```

But I'm using this loop right now which isn't working as I want it to:

`for($i = 0; $i <= count($names); $i++)`
`{ echo $i.$names[$i]."<br/>"; }`

and it's echoing this:

```
0. Alex
1. James
2. Jack
```

The problem is because we are starting from 0 because it's an array. If I put a starting point 1 it's missing the first object from the array.

What's the fix for that?

Comment: why not use a foreach loop? same output essentialy just imho easier when used on arrays

Comment: Echo `$i + 1` instead of `$i`?  If you want to add 1 to a value, `+ 1` does just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just increment your variable

```
$names = array('Alex','James','Jack');
for($i = 0; $i <= count($names); $i++) { 
    $j = $i+1;
    echo $j.$names[$i]."<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: Because I'm still drunk... Thanks. :)